# Resolving formula error in raster calculator of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have a problem with a formula to calculate the susceptibility to landslide that gives me errors when computing with "raster calculator" in arcgis 10.1.

The formula is exact but errors in the expressions: "(", ")" or "," and here is the formula:

```
Con("aspectU0" < 90,0,"aspectU0" > 90 & "aspectU0" < 180 , ("aspectU0" - 90) / 90,"aspectU0" > 180 & "aspectU0" < 270,(270 - "aspectU0") / 90,0,"aspectU0" > 270 & "aspectU0" < 360,0)
```

The following formula which is executable in arcgis 9.3 to be executable in arcgis 10.1. Can it be converted?

```
con([aspectdem] le 90, 0, [aspectdem] gt 90 & [aspectdem] le 180, ([aspectdem] - 90) / 90, [aspectdem] gt 180 & [aspectdem] le 270, (270 - [aspectdem]) / 90, 0,[aspectdemf] gt 270 & [aspectdemf] le 360, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Con(    "aspectU0" <= 90, 0 , Con(   ("aspectU0" > 90) & ("aspectU0" <= 180) , ("aspectU0" - 90) / 90 , Con(  ("aspectU0" > 180 ) & ("aspectU0" <= 270) , (270 - "aspectU0") / 90 ,  Con( ("aspectU0" > 270) & ("aspectU0" <= 360) ,0 )  )   )    )
```

I've put the embedded Con's for the conditional. I also changed < to <= because le means lesser or equal. There was a ",0" (before the last Con) that I removed because I could not find its utility.

Note that you will have NoData values if your aspect is larger than 360 (which does not occur in theory), but you do not handle the negative value (if I remember well, aspect is -1 when undefined(on flat terrain)

if I understand well what you want to do, you could also write :

```
Con(   ("aspectU0" > 90) & ("aspectU0" <= 180) , ("aspectU0" - 90) / 90 , Con(  ("aspectU0" > 180 ) & ("aspectU0" <= 270) , (270 - "aspectU0") / 90 ,  0 ) )
```

Comment: Thank you very much I have execute the formula  you asked me it works well :                                       Con( "aspectU0" <= 90, 0 , Con( ("aspectU0" > 90) & ("aspectU0" <= 180) , ("aspectU0" - 90) / 90 , Con( ("aspectU0" > 180 ) & ("aspectU0" <= 270) , (270 - "aspectU0") / 90 , Con( ("aspectU0" > 270) & ("aspectU0" <= 360) ,0 ) ) ) )